# How can I focus on the heading of an ng-template?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to focus on the heading of an ng-template. This is my ng-template tag: 
 I want to use a directive or the linked component to this html page to focus on the heading of this ng-template(Sample) at will. This is my current workaround, but it produces unexpected and seemingly unrelated bug. This bug causes the Sample tab to not be focused or selected(I have some other tabs, they can all be navigated through via selecting them)and nothing displays but an empty div. This is my workaround:(omitting irrelevant code). Note: This workaround works perfectly the first time I open an item, the Sample Tab is focused and selected, but after that I will close the item and open the same or a different item and the bug will happen, my console logging statements tell me that the active element is actually the name of the item i have selected, although that may be out of scope, I am really just looking for a competent way to focus on the heading of an ng-template.

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[autofocusing]"
})
ngAfterViewInit(){
        console.log('after view began');
        console.log('active element is:' + (document.activeElement as HTMLElement).innerText);
        if((document.activeElement as HTMLElement).innerText.trim() === 'Close'){
            var eleList = document.getElementsByClassName('slds-tabs--scoped__link');
            for(var i = 0; i < eleList.length; i++){
                if((eleList[i] as HTMLElement).innerText.trim() === 'DETAILS'){
                    this.element = (eleList[i] as HTMLElement);
                    //Otherwise Angular throws error: Expression has changed after it was checked.
                    // window.setTimeout(() =>
                    // {
                        (eleList[i] as HTMLElement).focus();
                    // });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log('after view ended');
        console.log('active element is:' + (document.activeElement as HTMLElement).innerText);
```